Fail to use selenium open Browser
I tried to use selenium to open a browser crawler, but encountered the following error regardless of using chrome or edge. My code is
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as 
EdgeService
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

service =EdgeService(r'C:\Users\K13483\Desktop\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)

and error is

WebDriverException: Message: <!-- IE friendly error message walkround.
if error message from server is less than
512 bytes IE v5+ will use its own error
message instead of the one returned by
server.
I confirm that the Edge version and driver are both 127.0.2651.98.
and try any way can find from internet but fail,and GPT4o can't too
This issue has been bothering me for 2 days, please help.

Do you need solution for strictly Edge? If you okay with Chrome driver, then I can help you. I dont have much knowledge on Edge.

I also have the same issue in Chrome. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or ideas, I can refer to them.

You are running Selenium Grid or Stand alone?

What's you mean?I run code in anaconda/jupyter
